# QGIS: multi column legend wrapping: how to keep layer symbols aligned horizontally?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend

In my legend I have one layer with a group heading and due to layout reasons I need it to be split in 2 columns:

[image]

The only work around I can think of is to set heading to `''` either in the layer panel which is ugly and results in a even quirkier legend layout or doing so in the legend item properties in the print composer which has no impact at all.

I am using QGIS 3.18.3

Comment: I suggest you add a picture of what you would like to achieve. Or would it be sufficient to simply remove the group header?

Comment: Technically a group header can't be removed but set to an empty string and the two possibilities to do so don't work out as expected just as i wrote in my question.

Comment: Rightclick the group in the legend item properties, set it to hidden - and it is removed from the legend.

Comment: That 'hidden' option is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The style you are expecting is only possible with the legend title.

To do so you have to:

1. Hide the group header (like [@Erik explained](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/400915/qgis-multi-column-legend-wrapping-how-to-keep-layer-symbols-aligned-horizontal#comment654109_400915))
2. Set the title of your legend to be "Housing Area"
3. Set margin around title and font of your title to get the result you are waiting for.

Note: Here there is a question that may give you more information about vertical alignment: [Vertically and Horizontally align the labels in multi-column QGIS legends](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/396432/vertically-and-horizontally-align-the-labels-in-multi-column-qgis-legends)

Comment: Actually I was aware of that question you linked but its answer doesn't make use of that very option. Also I didn't dive into that OP's issue since its complexity seemed way beyond my problem here but now I bookmarked it. Anyway many thanks for your answer!

Comment: Fine if it work. The question linked was only to give more info about vertical align rules.